# Can HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout -> Scancode Map be used to "redefine" the keyboard layout on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, keyboard-layout

On a computer where I have full admin rights, I changed the keyboard layout with the following registry entries

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout] 
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,01,00,3a,00,3a,00,01,00,1d,e0,5c,e0,00,00,00,00
```

which worked fine and as expected.

Now, on another computer where I don't heve the necessary privileges to change HKLM entries, I tried the same thing under HKCU:

```
REGEDIT4 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout] 
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,01,00,3a,00,3a,00,01,00,1d,e0,5c,e0,00,00,00,00
```

Unfortunatly, on this computer, it has no effect (that I could notice). I have rebooted the computer. The registry key was registered through `regedit`, and I can seem them with `regedit`.

So, can`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout -> "Scancode Map"` be used to redefine my keyboard layout, especially if I don't have the necessary rights to change HKLM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the following is an archived paper, I believe it's still valid for Win7: [Scan Code Mapper for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx).

> The following disadvantages are recognized:
>
> - Once the map is stored in the registry, a system reboot is required to activate it.
> - The mappings stored in the registry work at system level and apply to all users. **These mappings cannot be set to work differently depending on the current user.**
> - The current implementation restricts the functionality of the map such that mappings always apply to all keyboards connected to the system. **It is not currently possible to create a map on a per-keyboard basis.**